# shell script to find number of unique files in a directory as well its sub- directories?

Tags: unix

I’m trying to find number of unique files in a directory as well its sub- directories Is this possible?

Say for example there is a directory with 100 files. How would I count the number of unique files under that directory?

Comment: Which measure of uniqueness do you want: filename or content are the usual choices.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're asking about file names, you can

1. First, list all the files in the directory tree
2. Second, get the unique values from the list

To list all the files, you can use `find`.  Normally `find` prints the entire path name of each result, but since you just want to compare the base file names, you will have to customize its output:

```
find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

This will print each base file name, one per line.  Now you can get only the unique file names by sorting and then collapsing all adjacent entries that share a name into a single entry.  The `sort` command with the `-u` switch does this for you:

```
find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u
```

If you want to get a count of the number of repetitions of each unique file name, then just use `sort` by itself and use `uniq -c` to handle the collapsing and the counting:

```
find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Note that the above solution will get confused by file names that contain newline (`\n`) characters.  If you have any such file names, you should read in the `find` manual about null-terminating (instead of newline-terminating) your output.

Finally, if you're simply looking for a numeric output, pipe the whole thing through "wc -l" to count it.

```
find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c | wc -l
```